# Extending keystone.js auth

Tags: authorization, keystonejs

I'm trying to find a way to limit access to certain pages based on whether they are logged in as a keystone.js admin - is there a way to extend their existing admin auth to apply to pages outside of the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Yeoman generator, the `User` model has an `isAdmin` property. Within your Express route, you can determine if `req.user` exists, then if `req.user.isAdmin` is `true`.